# Ajax You are not authorized for this action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

when I make the following call in JavaScript:

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/Products/ProductRprt',
data: { data: jsonData },
....

It works. However, if I change the name of my controller function in any way, I receive the error message ‘You are not authorized for this action.’ It seems absurd that a name change would cause this issue. Has anyone encountered this and knows a solution?

There shouldn’t have been an error when I changed the name of the method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To better understand this site and how to get a positive result from posting here, please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask). In order to help you, we need much more detail than you've so far provided above. For instance, how did you change the controller name? Did you change the URL to match? Please show us those. What does the authorization checking code look like? What did you find when you used the debugger on the ASP.Net code?

Comment: Could you add the code? It would help us massively to see the controller and what decorators may or may not be on it...Also...maybe a stupid question...but are you changing the function name in both places?